# jQuery autoheight for UL

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the jQuery Accordion with nested UL/LI items for my menu (as opposed to divs). I want each panel to only be as big as it needs to be (not to be as big as the largest panel). I have tried setting **autoHeight: false** but it isn't doing anything. Any ideas how to make it work with a UL/LI structure?

```
<div class="LeftNav">
    <div class="menu vertical menu-vertical">
        <ul class="root static" id="accordion">
            <li class="static dynamic-children"><a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" title="Information Technology" href="/IT"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">IT</span></span></a>
            <ul class="dynamic">
                <li class="dynamic"><a class="dynamic menu-item" title="IT Requests" href="/IT/requests"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">IT Requests</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="dynamic"><a class="dynamic menu-item" title="Frequently asked questions" href="/IT/faqs"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">FAQs</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="dynamic"><a class="dynamic menu-item" title="Forms" href="/IT/forms"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Forms</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="dynamic"><a class="dynamic menu-item" title="Child 1" href="/HSE/child1"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Child 1</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="static dynamic-children"><a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" title="HSE" href="/HSE"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">HSE</span></span></a>
                <ul class="dynamic">
                    <li class="dynamic"><a class="dynamic menu-item" title="Child 1" href="/HSE/child1"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Child 1</span></span></a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" title="HSE" href="/commonly-used"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Commonly Used</span></span></a></li>
            <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" title="Human Resources, Payroll and Benefits" href="/human-resources-payroll-and-benefits"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">HR, Payroll and Benefits</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" title="Office Services and Supplies" href="/office-services-and-supplies"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Office Services and Supplies</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" title="Sales, Marketing and Leasing" href="/sales-marketing-and-leasing"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Sales, Marketing and Leasing</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they have replaced `autoHeight` with `heightStyle`

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

**heightStyle**

Type: String

Default: "auto"

Controls the height of the accordion and each panel. Possible values:

```
"auto": All panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel.
"fill": Expand to the available height based on the accordion's parent height.
"content": Each panel will be only as tall as its content.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a CSS issue. Try:

```
menu li {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck with that. :(

Comment: Do you have a fiddle we can see? Only the html will not help us answer the problem correctly. That's what I get on a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/wR4Yv/